# Imitating Web browsers behavior in Java

Tags: java, browser, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

When a Web browser is asked to load a URL it will issue an HTTP request to the Web server in order to get the response correspond to that HTTP request. After receiving the response it will pars the response (HTML documents) to fetch other resources if any. Therefore, Web browser will issue more HTTP requests toward the Web server automatically.

In Java we can use `java.net.URLConnection` to issue an HTTP request for a particular URL. The response will be available after very short time. Then we would need to parse the received HTML response on our own and issue an HTTP request for each of the detected resources one after the other.

- Is there any way by which we can issue those automated HTTP requests automatically as well in Java?
- Or at least is there any parser which parse the HTML document and extract list of all resources which should be requested?

Comment: Looking for " java simulate browser" might get you where you want to go. http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You are essentially asking "How do I write a web browser in Java?" which is far too broad a topic for the Question & Answer format that SO is supposed to be. Otherwise, you're asking for recommendation for an HTML parsing tool — see #4 in [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite a little unspecific. What is your intention? (Do you want to write a browser, test a server, or test a website?)

You might want to check [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), which is a Java package to run load tests on web servers.

You might also want to have a look at [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) which is allows you to write automated tests for websites and simulate browsers' behavior (i.e., send requests, receive and analyze responses...)

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I am going to test the Website. I do that usually by PhantomJS which is headless Web browser. Now I am in the step in which I need to get access to the JavaScript functions fetched by the Web browser. Using PhantomJS, currently, I have no access to the body of the HTTP responses. Then, I cannot get access to the JavaScript functions. But, one solution for me is to get the list of all HTTP requests and issue them to the Web server in order to have the response... Now, I am thinking maybe I can use Java instead of PhantomJS for this part of my project just to get the JavaScript functions...

Comment: I don't want to use Selenium Web driver but I will check the first link that you just suggested to see if it solves my problem. Thank you though...